# Is it feasible that the period in John 1:3-4 should be placed as καὶ χωρὶς αὐτοῦ ἐγένετο ⸂οὐδὲ(. here) ἕν ὃ γέγονεν ἐν αὐτῷ ζωὴ ἦν?

Tags: greek, john, grammar

This would make sense (the period before ἕν):

```
  and one did not even come about without Him.
  One thing which came into being by Him was life.
```

But no one seems to propose it.  So, the thrust of this question is why hasn't it been proposed?

P.S. a good argument for a period after ὃ γέγονεν is that ζωὴ is feminine. this relates to the question at [What is the correct punctuation of John 1:3-4?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/26837/what-is-the-correct-punctuation-of-john-13-4/55655#55655).   However, a period before or after ἕν still has the neuter relative pronoun ὃ modifying ζωὴ in either case. The lack of historic support related to this question implies support for a period after ὃ γέγονεν.

Comment: sorry, I misunderstood. I will withdraw the answer. In that case, I would answer your question in the negative

Comment: Not a problem.  You got me to clarify the question.

Comment: I also fixed some typing errors that made it unclear.

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible because έν means one. Oude means nor or not even. You cannot stop at neither, nor, not even. It requires the phrase - not even one.

By the way the English translations are right in punctuating the verse.